# How to faster `visit` in Capybara?

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I interacted with a website using Capybara, the driver i chose is capybara-webkit ,but the problem is that the code was stuck at `visit` and cost  about 5 minutes or more to load the page.
It was a terrible thing for me.
And my code is the following:

```
   def crawl(city_en)  
     #Global Setting  
      Capybara.current_driver = :webkit     
      Capybara.default_selector = :xpath   
      Capybara.app_host = 'http://hotel.qunar.com'  
      # Set user agent    
      page.driver.header 'User-Agent',"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)"    
      @city = city_en
      @uri = "/city/#{@city}"
      puts 'Visiting...'
      page.visit @uri 
      @page = Nokogiri::HTML page.driver.browser.body 
    end
```

I am not sure if there something wrong with my code, if not ,are there some tricks to faster webkit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara is acceptance test framework. For automating interaction with websites you can use [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize). Mechanize automatically stores and sends cookies, follows redirects, and can follow links and submit forms.